# Advanced Command Prompt Replacement

Tags: windows, command-line

Quite frequently I'll have small `batch` or `powershell` scripts to perform tedious work, and prefer to be able to operate out of the CLI as apposed to a GUI. The minor details are irrelevant, but essentially I am looking for a third-party emulator to replace command prompt and powershell (not that there is anything wrong with them).

**What this application should be able to do:**

1. Store alias commands such as `cp -ra` being `robocopy /E` (Purely an example)
2. Run scripts within the same window (similar to running a `.ps1` in Powershell)
3. Have shortcut commands such as `crtl` + `v` pasting from your clipboard
4. I would **love** the ability to open documents and edit them in the command window (similar to `nano` or `vim` in linux - and no, I do not want Vim as another application)

This program can be open source/propriety and can be either free or paid. Keep in mind I have had a look at the following solutions:

- [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/)
  works very well with multiple tabs and the ability to have new tabs, with different "palettes". I love the fact I can force it to be the default emulator for Windows but I am unsure if I can store alias, or have an inbuilt text editor (the ability to edit existing documents inside the same CLI that I use for commands is really the biggest thing I want...)
- [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) - There are no valid reasons I do not like Cygwin...I just do not like it.

**Note:**

The command `edit.exe`, `copy con` and `edlin` are not valid options. They do not operate on a 64 Version OS.

Furthermore, I do not want to use VIM as an option as (a) I dislike the complexity (yes, even over the functionality) and (b) it's just another program, I want to call within an emulator, edit and then break out.

Comment: For alias, try`doskey alias=echo Hello`

Comment: You might have a look at [Take](https://jpsoft.com/) or the free variant [TCC/LE](https://jpsoft.com/tccle-cmd-replacement.html), the former 4DOS. I didn't use it, so I can't recommend it. If you like it, answer your own question with it.

Comment: @Thomas, the `doskey` function helps alot, so thank you. Should TCC/LE be valid I shall let you know.

Comment: @Thomas Please answer this question.

Comment: Hmm, not sure. I wrote an answer, but I don't know how it fulfills the `edit` problem.

Comment: And I don't exactly know what you mean by requirement 2 "Run scripts within the same window". Don't all batch files run in CMD in the same window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the aliases, Windows has the built-in command `doskey`. It cannot handle spaces in the alias name, so `cp -ra` cannot be specified as an alias on its own. However, `doskey hi=echo Hello` works.

The developers of [4DOS (Wikipedia)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/4DOS) have a successor for Windows, available as the commercial product [Take](https://jpsoft.com/) (~80 USD) or in its free edition [TCC/LE](https://jpsoft.com/tccle-cmd-replacement.html).

It

- supports aliases (`alias`), but does not support `doskey` mentioned before
- supports <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Disadvantages:

- It takes a while to get used to the command prompt. To get the "original" CMD-like command line prompt, you have to `prompt $P$G` but I did not figure out how to make it persistent.